# Enzyme Unit testing private React Components

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have a component which looks something like :

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {

 render() {
  return(
        <div>
           <PrivateComponent1/>
           <PrivateComponent2/>
           <PrivateComponent3/>
          </div>
      );
 }
}
```

Now I need to write unit tests for the private components with enzyme. I could think of only two approaches to unit test them

1. Use `mount` instead of `shallow` and mount MyComponent but then then we need to worry about the 
    private components dependencies.
2. `export` those private components and write unit tests separately, but they may not be useful anywhere else in the project and exporting may not make any sense.

Please advice if there exists some standard way

Comment: Write Unit tests for PrivateComponent separately instead of writing them for MyComponent.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri How can we write unit tests for these private components separately without exporting them